# In x86 assembly, when should I use global variables instead of local variables?

Tags: assembly, x86, global-variables, local-variables, i386

I am creating some small programs with x86 assembly, and it's my first time using a low level language so I'm not used to it.

In high level languages I rarely use global variables, but I've seen a lot of tutorials using global variables in assembly, so I'm not sure when to use global variables instead of local variables.

By global variables I mean data created in the .bss and .data segments, and by local variables I mean data allocated on the stack of the current procedure, using the stack pointer.

Right now, I am using local variables, and parameters a lot more than global variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to use global variables, but it's less complicated to set them up, making tutorials easier to understand.  Stick with local variables if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, prefer locals that you keep in registers, or on the stack if needed.**

"variable" is a high level concept that doesn't truly exist in asm.  So it's just a question of where you keep the data that you're working on.  But sure, local vs. global var is a good way to talk about static storage (.data / .bss / .rodata) vs. stack memory, if you're thinking in terms of *un-optimized* C where every variable really does have an address in memory.

In asm, code with fewer instructions is usually easier to understand.  Removing store/reload `mov` instructions in favour of just keeping data in registers usually makes it easier to follow.  The joy of writing in asm is finding ways to do the same job with fewer (and/or cheaper) instructions, and uselessly storing/reloading to memory is the opposite of that.  It makes your code ugly, IMO.

---

Globals suck in asm for all the reasons they suck in higher level languages (unclear data flow when functions read/write them), and other considerations that you might not think about in a high-level language:  every instruction that uses a static address like `[my_var]` has a 4-byte `disp32` as part of the addressing mode, vs. `[esp+8]` only needing 2 extra bytes (SIB because of ESP as the base, and disp8 because `+8` fits in a sign-extended 8-bit integer).  Or if you make a stack frame with EBP, you save the SIB byte in addressing modes.

Globals are maybe justifiable in toy programs that basically are just one function, if you don't care about efficiency and would rather define your memory layout with labels and `dd` / `dw` / `db` instead of just offsets into the stack frame.  But often you can just keep everything in registers in that case.  (Especially on x86-64, where you have 15 GP registers other than the stack pointer, vs. IA-32 only having 7, or 6 if you dedicate EBP to being a frame pointer.)

**Using lots of globals in asm examples/tutorials is maybe a leftover style habit from old ISAs like 6502 or 8051 that didn't have stack-pointer-relative addressing modes**, and thus local variables on the call-stack were a bad thing.  (See [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/why-do-c-to-z80-compilers-produce-poor-code/6099#comment15353_6100))

It's maybe also / instead done as a simple way to name variables for the purpose of making an example, but in asm that's what comments are for.  There is no compiler to turn your self-documenting code into efficient code.  Or you can do what MSVC's asm output does, and define assemble-time constants for the offset of each local relative to the stack frame.  e.g.

```
foo equ -12
func:
   push  ebp
   mov   ebp, esp
   sub   esp, 24
   ...

   mov  eax, [ebp + foo]
   leave
   ret
```

---

### Even better: keep your local variables in registers

For most variables, there's usually no need to spill them to memory anywhere.  Use comments to keep track of which variable or expression is where.

If it doesn't hurt efficiency, often you can have a 1:1 correspondence between registers and the high-level variables you're thinking about when designing the algorithm.  e.g. maybe `x` stays in `edi` for the whole function, including in all blocks after branching.  (And some other registers are mostly used as scratch space for computations and stuff loaded from memory.)

In that case you'd have a block of comments at the top of a function documenting this.  If some of the registers are set near the top of the function, those source lines can be good places for such comments.

---

Memory-destination `sub dword [loop_counter], 1` has 6 cycle latency on typical modern x86 ISAs (5 cycle store-forwarding + 1 cycle ALU).  If you use this as part of a loop, it will run at *best* one iteration per 6 cycles.  This is part of why C compilers with optimization disabled make such slow code.  Doing this by hand is basically shooting yourself in the foot.

`dec ecx` / `jnz` only has 1 cycle latency, so a loop without any store/reload as part of a loop-carried dependency can run as fast as 1 iteration per clock cycle.  (For loops of up to 4 uops on current Intel CPUs; up to 5 instructions if the dec/jnz or `cmp/jcc` at the bottom macro-fuses into a single uop.  Otherwise you hit front-end bottlenecks.  Speaking of which, memory-destination read-modify-write operations are always at least 2 uops.)

---

## When to use globals

Allocating a big array in the BSS is easy for testing stuff.  Then you can get the address into a register with `mov edi, array` in NASM syntax, or `mov edi, OFFSET array` in MASM syntax.  So you can use that to test code that's written to take a pointer to an array as an input.

(On some Linux kernel versions, anonymous hugepages might work differently for BSS vs. mmapped regions, but I think they do work on BSS regions in modern kernels.  Not on file-backed `.data` / `.rodata` regions, though, except maybe if you dirty the private `.data` pages, essentially them anonymous.)

#### Static constant data is useful

The most common use-case is probably strings in `section .rodata`  (or `section .rdata` on Windows).

```
section .rodata                     ; linked as part of the TEXT segment
msg: db "Hello World", 10
msglen equ $ - msg                  ; assemble-time constant
```

Often you need a string in memory to pass by reference to a system call like `write` or a function like `puts` or `printf` (e.g. as a format string).  Having it in read-only memory and materializing a pointer is a lot easier than storing a string to memory from immediates, like with `` push `rld\n` ``  or

```
mov dword [esp], "Hell"
mov dword [esp+4], "o Wo"
...
mov ecx, esp              ; pointer to the string
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  Did I offend a fan of global variables?  [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) is a pretty nice example of using registers as locals, and a small buffer on the stack.  [Extreme Fibonacci](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618) is a longer program heavily code-golfed.  The source code is a bit messy, but does have some examples of documenting register usage in comments.

Comment: This pretty much sums-up the things for me: *"Globals suck in asm for all the reasons they suck in higher level languages"*. Btw, I upvoted and following your answers, keep up good work!