# x86 Assembly (Advanced Indexing Mode): How do I access memory at a variable amount ahead of a start address?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att, addressing-mode

I am trying to read a section of memory, byte by byte, starting from the memory address stored in the EAX register. I push the current byte to the EBX register. However, when I execute the following line of code (advanced indexing mode):

```
movb byteCount(%eax), %ebx
```

I get the following error:

> **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.**

It seems that Assembly doesn't supporting using a label in advanced indexing. How would I go about emulating this same action without using a label or register before (%eax)? Below is the data section:

```
.data
    str:
        .string "abcdefg"
        
    byteCount:
        .int 1
```

Comment: Assembly supports it. That's why your code passed the assembler. The crash is at runtime, not assembly time.

Comment: @RaymondChen Does byteCount need to be of a certain type in order for it to be supported by Assembly?

Comment: In that context, `byteCount` is the label address, not the dword that happens to be in memory there.  You need to load all runtime-variable things into registers to use them in addressing modes; x86 doesn't do memory-indirect addressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In that context, `byteCount` is the label address, not the dword that happens to be in memory there**.  You need to load all runtime-variable things into registers to use them in addressing modes; x86 doesn't do memory-indirect addressing.

```
   mov    byteCount, %edx           # dword load
   movzbl (%eax, %edx), %ebx        # zero-extending byte load
```

Or of course you could use `add byteCount, %eax` and deref `(%eax)`.  Or better, you could keep `byteCount` in a register in the first place, where you need it anyway.  That's what registers are for.  [In x86 assembly, when should I use global variables instead of local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356495/in-x86-assembly-when-should-i-use-global-variables-instead-of-local-variables) (usually you shouldn't).

---

`movb` into EBX is an error (operand-size mismatch), so certainly that's not what you actually ran.  But that would access a byte at `bytecount[ (uintptr_t)eax ]`.  If you'd used just `mov`, it would be a dword load.

But regardless, **the sum of two addresses is rarely a valid address, so it segfaults**.  Your debugger should have told you the faulting address so you could see it was far from `str`.

---

Related:

- [How i can access a variable data using a variable value in adress like [ var_+[second_byte] ]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843818/how-i-can-access-a-variable-data-using-a-variable-value-in-adress-like-var-s) (Intel-syntax near duplicate).
- [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)
- [A couple of questions about [base + index*scale + disp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936196/a-couple-of-questions-about-base-indexscale-disp) (AT&T addressing mode syntax)